# Количество пробелов Java conventions

Tags: java, code-style, соглашения

Мне не понятен следующий пункт Java conventions:
"Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4)."

Что переводится как:
"В качестве единицы отступов следует использовать четыре пробела. Точная конструкция отступа (пробелы или символы табуляции) не указана. Табуляция должна быть установлена ровно каждые 8 пробелов (а не 4)."

Мне не понятно, так 4 использовать пробела или 8? Или в каких-то случаях 4, а в каких-то 8?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле эти три предложения мало связаны между собой и все о разном.

1. *Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation* - здесь речь о единице измерения табуляции, а не о том, сколько в отступе должно быть пробелов. Так же как единицей длины является метр, но это не означает, что всё на свете что имеет длину, равно одному метру. Может быть и 2, и 4,5 и 0,345.
2. *The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified* - здесь речь о том, что не регламентируется, как делать отступы - табами или пробелами.
3. *Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4)* - это просто соотношение таба и количества пробелов. Как в километре 1000 метров (или, например, в футе 12 дюймов), так и в табе 8 пробелов (или две единицы табуляции).

Традиционно используется 4 пробела, но в некоторых случаях 8 ([в документе, откуда этот текст](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-indentation.html), есть примеры). Но никто не запрещает вам в личных проектах использовать 2 пробела (0.5 единицы), 3 (3/4 единицы) или 7 (1 3/4 единицы). На работе скорее всего запрещают стандарты.